# Android partially active Activity

Tags: android

I have an activity A. I am creating a kind of tutorial for user for this activity, to teach him how he can use the app on that screen.

For that, my requirement is :
I want to blur all the views of the activity except one view. I want to prompt user to click on that view through a hand image pointing at that view.

Nothing should happen if the user clicks on the blurred/greyed out area, but if he taps on that particular active view, it should react to that touch.

I was thinking of using a full screen fragment for this. The Fragment will take the following input from the activity :

- for what coordinates, is should not blur the screen and pass the touch event to the activity
- the coordinates on which it should show that pointing hand image.

After from these coordinates, the fragment background would be blur.

I wanted to confirm if that's possible, to make the fragment partially active, i.e. delegate it's touch events to the activity for a particular view of the activity.

Also, please let me know if there is any other better approach of achieving the same thing.

**Edit1 :**

Thinking of using a fragment here, because I'd want this type of behaviour on different screen in future. In that case, I'd make that fragment generic which takes some inputs (as described above) and use it on different screens.

Comment: How about Android Showcase Library? Import the code from Github and customize according to your design.

Comment: Didn't know about this library at all !. Thanks for the information. I'll first evaluate the library then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a very good library called `SCV` which does what you're trying to achieve, you're able to customize the styles for it too. I've used this for first time the app is opened to show the user a tutorial.

According to their [Github](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView)

> The ShowcaseView (SCV) library is designed to highlight and showcase specific parts of apps to the user with a distinctive and attractive overlay. This library is great for pointing out points of interest for users, gestures, or obscure but useful items.

Further Reading:

- [Android Arsenal - Showcase Views Tutorial](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1408)
- [ShowCaseView on Android - Indipendev](https://indiependev.wordpress.com/2014/12/30/using-showcaseview-on-android/)

[image]

Comment: woah ! I didn't know about this library at all. Thanks buddy ! Let me evaluate   it.

Comment: No problem, once you've got your head wrapped around it, it's very useful.

Comment: what did you think? useful?

Comment: yeah, pretty useful ! . It doesn't have everything that I need, so I am going to fork it and modify it accordingly. But yeah, good find :)

Comment: good man, when you've forked it. you mind me taking a look at your modifications? I'd be intrigued in what features you would add to it. (if you want to make your changes public of course)

Comment: yeah sure, I'd be making it public.

Answer (score 1):

I found it much easier to include an 'extra' layout around the UI of my activity, and then to add a highest-z grey mostly-transparent filter to it and put the instructions on that.

Each "step" of the instructions was a different layout that was dynamically loaded into that layout container as they clicked. (Just another approach)

---

The 'container' layout is a: FrameLayout

then in my Activity I have: (ignore bad naming)

```
private void addOverlayLayout() {

    frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.framelayoutInner);
    frameLayout3 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.framelayout3);

    frameLayout3.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    frameLayout3.setAlpha(0.3f);

    // Dynamically create a relativelayout which will be appended to framelayout
    relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());
    relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams
            .MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    instructionOverlays.add(createSimpleClickInstruction(R.layout.instruction_reader_1));
    instructionOverlays.add(createSimpleClickInstruction(R.layout.instruction_reader_2));

    if (FullscreenReaderActivity.isFirstRun) {
        displayNextGuide();
    }

}

public void displayNextGuide() {

    // clean relative layout if it has views
    relativeLayout.removeAllViews();
    // clean frame layout if it has child (safe if empty)
    frameLayout.removeView(relativeLayout);

    if (!isFirstRun) {
        return;
    }

    if (instructionOverlays.size() > 0) {
        runOnUiThread(instructionOverlays.get(0));
        instructionOverlays.remove(0);
    } else {
        frameLayout3.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        frameLayout3.setAlpha(1.0f);
    }
}

public Runnable createSimpleClickInstruction(final int resource) {
    return new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                    resource,
                    relativeLayout,
                    true
            );
            relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    displayNextGuide();
                }
            });
            frameLayout.addView(relativeLayout);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: How'd you partially active thing? All the views should be greyed out except the one, which I'll prompt the user to click on. Nothing should happen if the user clicks on the blurred/greyed out area, but if he taps on that particular active view, it should react to that touch.

Comment: added the code I have, if you want partially active then make your layout non-grey there(probably easier to never make it grey there in the first place), and have arrows pointing/telling them where to click/etc. I would just put my own invisible view there with onclicklistener that would by code invoke the target below it. and not even bother with passing the click through.(that is outside my use case, mine was more just 'instruction' not requiring them to click other than 'next', 'next', etc.

Comment: So after looking at the SCV library mentioned in @Bradley Wilson's post, it probably would be easier than manually doing it like I did. I did this as an exercise in seeing if I 'could' do it. But this method at least doesn't require a library.